# Major differences between ethers-js and ethers-rs

Tags: javascript, ethers.js, rust

I haven't used ethers-rs before, are there any extra features there compared to ethers-js.

Learning rust is not an issue here, I'm pretty comfortable with both javascript and rust.

Comment: Beyond that one is written in javascript/typescript and the other in rust, perhaps the major difference is that ethersj.s can run in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also pretty new in the smart contract sphere, but simplyfied:
rust/C/C++ for the solana-ecosystem
solidity with python/js frameworks for the ethereum ecosystem

pls correct me if I'm mistaken here.